# Do you have a copy of Unipath-0.2.0.tar.gz?

Tags: python

I need a copy of this library installed on my system because my software depends on this library.

Unfortunately, at the moment, it's impossible install it trough easy_install:

```
andrea@puzzle:~$ sudo easy_install Unipath
[sudo] password for andrea: 
Searching for Unipath
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Unipath/
Reading http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/unipath/
Download error: (-2, 'Name or service not known') -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/unipath/
Download error: (-2, 'Name or service not known') -- Some packages may not be found!
Best match: Unipath 0.2.0
Downloading http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/unipath/Unipath-0.2.0.tar.gz
error: Download error for http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/unipath/Unipath-0.2.0.tar.gz: (-2, 'Name or service not known')
```

I think that something weird happened on the DNS entry of `sluggo.scrapping.cc`.
How can I get this library?

I searched for a mirror on google but I didn't find it. 
Do you know if there is a another place from where I can download this library?

Or ... do you have a copy of this library and you can send it to me?

Comment: the DNS entry is dropped for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the original author who confirmed me that there was a problem with the DNS entry and he's going to solve it.

He also uploaded the latest tarball to pypi, so now you can install it with `easy_install Unipath`.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/python-file-system-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a421d749eff8a230/4eacafbf70b6c04b?hl=en&q=unipath+python#4eacafbf70b6c04b) newsgroup post written my Mike Orr (the creator of Unipath). In the last sentence he says that he's moving the project from the [old server](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc) to Bitbucket. So may be that the problem will be fixed when the moving is finished.

Mike Orr message is dated March 10 2009, at the time of writing March 29 2009 I can see yet the source code on http://bitbucket.org/sluggo/unipath

**Workaround**

I found an .egg file in the backup archive of old system of mine. I uploaded the file on the internet.

But I think it solve the problem only for those people who have python 2.5. To install it use:

```
easy_install http://trash-cli.googlecode.com/files/Unipath-0.2.1-py2.5.egg
```

I hope the problem on the sluggo.scrapping.cc server would be soon fixed.